# github locks up mac terminal when using pull command

Tags: git, github, terminal

I'm in the process of learning github on mac (command-line) and whenever I do `git pull origin master` i get this

```
# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
".git/MERGE_MSG" 7L, 293C
```

the terminal seems to lock up  and doesn't allow me to enter anything immediately, then when it finally does allow me to enter text it seems like it doesn't recognize git commands.

Is this a bug in git or am i missing something?

Comment: Does it really lock up or are you just not familiar with `vi`?

Comment: I can't exactly tell you why, but git wants you to enter a commit message, and you are most probably in the text editor vim.

Comment: ah i see, yes I'm unfamiliar with vim. how do i enter and save the comment then contenue on?

Comment: type `i` to insert a comment then press esc and type `:wq`

Comment: If you're not familiar with `vi` aren't you locked up?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

You're in the text editor, vim! It's a *modal* text editor, so you would need to:

1. Press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter *insert mode*.
2. Now you can type your message, as if you were in a normal
   (non-modal) text editor.
3. Press <kbd>esc</kbd> to go back to *command mode*.
4. Then type `:w` followed by <kbd>enter</kbd> to save.
5. Finally `:q` followed by <kbd>enter</kbd> to quit.

Comment: It's great that git just assumes everyone knows vim.

Comment: @user124384 Git tries to use your `$EDITOR` environment variable, but falls back to `vi` if it can't find one. You can configure the fallback via git config's `core.editor`. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#coreeditor-mjjck

Comment: where I can type `i` ?

Comment: @val-kharitonashvili On a querty keyboard, it's adjacent to `u` and `o` ;) But really, as long as the terminal has focus, it should work.

Comment: Why does this even happen? I have always been doing `git merge master` and in the past 2 days, I'm seeing this...

Answer (score 19):

Make it simple.

Type `:wq` and <kbd>enter</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

The editor looks like to be *vim* according to your descriptions.
This console is simply telling you to write some message for the commit you want to make, and it is compulsory as it does.

- Just type `i` and you'll go in the `-- INTER --` mode, now you can write your comments.
- After you have done writing, press `esc` key in your keyboard and you'll go to command mode. (*see on the bottom of the console*)
- Now save changes by writing `:w` followed by pressing `enter` key

[image: Writing <code>:w</code> command]

- You can quit now by writing `:q` followed by pressing `enter` key

[image: Writing <code>:q</code> command]

- Hurray! Finally you're back to the main console.

Answer (score 2):

More simple is first  <kbd>ESC</kbd>  and then <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> (lowercase).

Answer (score 1):

Run this command

```
git config --global core.editor "gedit"
```

Add your message in this file and save it.
Go back pull now.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by executing following steps

1. Remove **#MERGE_MSG#**

   `rm .git/\#MERGE_MSG#`
2. Remove **MERGE_HEAD**

   `rm .git/MERGE_HEAD`

Additionally, I explicitly set git's editor to an editor that I am familiar with *vim* (you can set *nano*)

```
`git config --global core.editor "vim"`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do 
`git checkout --merge yourbranch`

A three-way merge between the current branch, your working tree contents, and the new branch is done, and you will be on the new branch.

Answer (score 0):

Problems usually happen when we misspell something. 
It is more likely this command you are interested in:

```
git commit -m "message"
```

if there was a problem, it might say something like

```
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 2 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

and use:

```
git pull
```

which should lead to:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

Then it is good to check:

```
git status
```

and try pushing again:

```
git push
```