# Git pull - can't submit merge message

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, commit-message

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [github locks up mac terminal when using pull command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046122/github-locks-up-mac-terminal-when-using-pull-command)

I am using Git via the terminal on the mac.
I have encountered an annoying problem recently when I try to perform `git pull`.
After performing `git pull` I receive the following error message:

```
Merge ssh://example.com/repository.git
# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts:
# the commit.
```

The issue is that I can't enter anything. My terminal seems stuck and there isn't anything I seem to be able to do about it. I am reasonably new to Git so it may be a simple mistake I am making.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744081/why-is-git-prompting-me-for-a-post-pull-merge-commit-message) that for some people the text editor opens at this point. This certainly isn't the case at my end. It also states there that I can use the --no-edit flag to merge without a message, but even this does not seem to work at my end.

I am a bit clueless at the moment, stuck and unable to push any changes to my server.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

This is vim, it's a common unix editor

press:

```
:wq
```

that's it. (w=write q=quit)

Comment: And if you did want to insert something you would type "i" and Vim goes in to edit mode. To exit edit mode just hit "escape".

Comment: simple but yet difficult to find for windows users like me. thanks for it :)

Comment: Damn. And I thought that I will never be stuck in VI.

Comment: ":wq" is not a button to be pressed.

Comment: https://www.commitstrip.com/en/2017/05/29/trapped  :o)

Answer (score 24):

When you see this, an editor already opened, because you see this ;) I guess it opens `vi`, or a derivate of this. Google for it to find out how to use it, but it seems you prefer to change the editor instead

```
git config --global core.editor "emacs"
```

I prefer `nano` :)