# Cannot get past the comment section after git commit?

Tags: git, commit, git-commit, git-bash

After I do a git commit, it would prompt me to comment so I can push to bitbucket and normally I press alt+x, then I exit and then git push. But for some reason, it's not letting me exit.

```
committed new changes to bitbucket

Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
   new file:   blocks/folder-navigation.block
   new file:   blocks/index-album.block
```

....

Comment: This is what I am getting on the bottom of the files.... {-- ^X mode (^]^D^E^F^I^K^L^N^O^Ps^U^V^Y)}

Comment: Could it be opening up another editor like vim or ed? Paste a screenshot.

Comment: That means your default git editor is [nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/), you can change your [default editor for commit message in git](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2596835/105104)

Comment: by the way the `^` char usually mean `ctrl`, meaning that for exiting you would nned to press `ctrl`+`X`

Comment: Yup. I think I got it, it was in vim. Pressing zz helped me exit and save. I will try this today.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046122/github-locks-up-mac-terminal-when-using-pull-command

Answer (score 12):

The editor looks like to be *vim* according to your descriptions.
This console is simply telling you to write some message for the commit you want to make, and it is compulsory as it does.

- Just type `i` and you'll go in the `-- INTER --` mode, now you can write your comments.
- After you have done, press `esc` key in your keyboard and you'll go to command mode. (*see on the bottom of the console*)
- Now save changes by writing `:w` followed by pressing `enter` key

[image: You can see the screenshot here for your reference]

- You can quit now by writing `:q` followed by pressing `enter` key

[image: you can see the screenshot here for your reference]

- Hurray! Now you're back to the main console.

Comment: @SandstormNick If an answer is helpful, we simply upvote it. Thanks.